# Will the garbage collector collect the objects created by this C# code?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class State
{
    public abstract void HandleState();
}

public class StateA : State
{
    public override void HandleState()
    {
       // do stuff here
       ....

       // this returns a new state object, and there are multiple, like StateB, StateC etc.
       State newState = GetNewState(); 
       newState.HandleState();
    }
}
```

Assuming that state objects keep getting returned ad-infinitum, will the garbage collector ever be able to collect objects generated by this code?

Comment: The garbage collection is the least of your problems. There is a stack overflow coming your way *fast*.

Comment: It will depend on what objects your GetNewState function returns. Those objects can register themselves somewhere in the static objects, thus becoming the long time dwellers of the heap.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You're assuming that `StateA` always returns *another `StateA` instance* when calling `GetNewState`.  If it returns a *new* state, then that doesn't happen.  State machines result in each state doing something and then computing the next state.  So as long as he has less than a few thousand state transitions he may well not overflow the stack.  If he has more than that then yes, it's a concern.

Comment: @Servy, I'm actually assuming `StateB.HandleState()`, `StateC.HandleState()`, etc. also unconditionally create a new random state and invoke its `HandleState()` method. At least that's what I understand from the question, I may, of course, be wrong.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Then the question remains of whether or not there is a final state, and how many states it takes to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that depends on what GetNewState returns. If you are creating stack overflow (as Frédéric Hamidi pointed out) by creating new instances of StateA, then you'll get a [StackOverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (most likely before the GC would try to run).

However, provided GetNewState() returns an instance of something else that *doesn't* create objects that are in turn creating new State objects recursively, then they will eventually get garbage collected at some point after they are no longer referenced (garbage collection is non deterministic and will clean up unused memory when it gets around to it).

Example of an implementation that wouldn't cause a stack overflow:

```
public class StateB : State
{
   public override void HandleState()
   {
     // do stuff here - that doesn't keep creating new State objects.
     ....
   }
}
```

As Eugene Podskal pointed out, those created classes could create a reference to themselves that would cause them to not get garbage collected. Such as:

```
public class StateC : State
{
   private static List<StateC> _myStates = new List<StateC>();

   public StateC()
   {
       //Unless items are removed at some point from _myStates, they 
       // won't get garbage collected.
       _myStates.Add(this);
   }

   public override void HandleState()
   {
     // do stuff here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  You're holding onto all of the references to these old `State` objects in the stack, which you continually delve down in without (apparently) ever coming back up from.  Since you're holding onto references to the old state objects, they won't be GCed.

Once (if) you get to whatever point at which you don't generate a new state and "go back up the stack" then the objects will be able to be reclaimed.